# Unity - GetKeyDown and GetKey using the same KeyCode to get a delay on input if held down

Tags: unity-game-engine

I an trying to get the user input do two different behaviors with the same input key.

like this :

```
 if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
```

Making a tetris game: The goal is, tapping "D" once, I want tetromino to move one world unit per tap. AND when holding down the same key "D" I want the block to move right continuously until it reaches the edge of the game board, without having to tap.

This sort of works with the code above but, the problem I have is that tapping once moves 2 or 3 world unit instead of once because there is no delay before unity realizes that I am holding the key down.

I would like unity to wait .5 seconds before activating "Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)" so that I can keep the behavior "Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D)"

Bottom line,

- I want to be able to tap "D" to move one world unit per tap
- I want the block to move continuously right until it reaches the edge of the game board if I hold down "D" but, only after holding it down for .5 seconds

How can I do this ?

Full code for the Tetromino.cs:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Tetromino : MonoBehaviour {
    //#####################################################################################################
    //#####################################################################################################
    float fallTimer = 0f;                 // timer counting the seconds to check if mino needs to fall
    public float fallSpeed = 1f;          // variable to determine how fast the mino needs to fall
    public bool allowRotation = true;
    public bool limitRotation = false;
    //#####################################################################################################
    //#####################################################################################################

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }
    //#####################################################################################################
    //#####################################################################################################
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        CheckUserInput();  // --------------------------- // Checks the user input every frames
        FallBehavior();   // checks if the block needs to fall and increments the timer 
    }
    //#####################################################################################################
    //#####################################################################################################
    void CheckUserInput()  
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))                  // moves the mino to the right
        {
            transform.position += new Vector3(1,0,0);
            if (CheckIsValidPosition()) // if minos is not in a valid position, the transform pushes the minos
            {                           // back to the left, to keep it inside the grid

            }
            else
            {
                transform.position += new Vector3(-1, 0, 0); // this counters the first attempt to move
            }
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))             // moves the mino to the left
        {
            transform.position += new Vector3(-1, 0, 0);
            if (CheckIsValidPosition())
            {

            }
            else
            {
                transform.position += new Vector3(1, 0, 0);
            }
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))             // rotates the mino
        {
            if (allowRotation)
            {
                if (limitRotation)                                //limited rotation ON, to prevent rotating outside the grid
                {                                                 // after the tetromino landed at the bottom
                    if (transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z >= 90)
                    {
                        transform.Rotate(0, 0, -90);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        transform.Rotate(0, 0, 90);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    transform.Rotate(0, 0, 90);                   // 90 degrees rotation on the mino
                }
                if (CheckIsValidPosition())
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    if (limitRotation)
                    {
                        if (transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z >= 90)
                        {
                            transform.Rotate(0, 0, -90);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            transform.Rotate(0, 0, 90);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        transform.Rotate(0, 0, -90);
                    }


                }

            }


        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
        {
            transform.position += new Vector3(0, -1, 0);  // makes the mino go down when pressing 
            if (CheckIsValidPosition())
            {

            }
            else
            {
                transform.position += new Vector3(0, 1, 0);
            }
        }
    }
    //#####################################################################################################
    //#####################################################################################################
    /// <summary>
    /// Makes the block fall by 1 unit and checks how fast it needs to fall
    /// </summary>
    void FallBehavior()
    {
        if (Time.time - fallTimer >= fallSpeed)  // on the first frame, Time.time = 0 & fallTimer = 0
                                                 // so 0 - 0 = 0, is it >= then fallSpeed = 1? no
                                                 // so the if statement does not exectute, block dont fall
                                                 // after 1 sec, Time.time = 1 & fallTimer = 0
                                                 // so 1 - 0 = 1, is it >= then fallSpeed = 1? yes
                                                 // so block falls after 1 sec, because we increment it
                                                 // in the if statment also
        {
            transform.position += new Vector3(0, -1, 0); // moves the mino down 

            fallTimer = Time.time;   // Time.time check the time since game started and is assigned
        }                            // to fallTimer so that the timer updates every frame 
                                     // when called in the Update method. fallTimer = 0, 1, 2, 3 ... 

        if (CheckIsValidPosition()) // also helps checking if the Y is invalid, which tells the game to spawn 
        {                            // the next tetromino when Y is less <= to the bottom of the grid 

        }
        else
        {
            transform.position += new Vector3(0, 1, 0);
            enabled = false; // disables the current piece, because it is at the bottom. So that the controls are not still
                             // attached to the current piece, after the next one spawned
            FindObjectOfType<Game>().SpawnNextTetromino(); // spawns the next tetromino after the last one reached the bottom
        }
    }

    //#####################################################################################################
    //#####################################################################################################
    /// <summary>
    /// check the position of the individual tiles of the minos (children of the prefab)
    /
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    bool CheckIsValidPosition()
    {
        foreach (Transform mino in transform)
        {
            Vector2 pos = FindObjectOfType<Game>().RoundingTheMinoPosition (mino.position);
            if (FindObjectOfType<Game>().CheckIsInsideGrid(pos) == false)
            {
                return false;
            }

        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Full code of Game.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Game : MonoBehaviour {

    public static int gridWidth = 10;  // fixed grid size varibles
    public static int gridHeight = 20; // for the blocks to fall in

    // the grid need to be in a 2d array and we want to store all the x and y values for each world unit of the grid
    // so that we can know which point on the grid are beind occupied by tetrominos that fell in.
    // 
    // the array is gonna store the transforms so we use "gridWidth" and "gridHeight" to define the size of the array.
    public static Transform[,] grid = new Transform[gridWidth, gridHeight];

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        SpawnNextTetromino();  // spawns the first tetromino in the game

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    public void SpawnNextTetromino() // the Resources folder is included when the game compiles, we placed our prefabs  
    {                               // in "Assets\Resources\Prefabs" to allow instantiation in the code.

        // we cast a gameobject -> "(GameObject)" to let "Instantiate" know what we want to instantiate.
        GameObject nextTetromino = (GameObject)Instantiate(Resources.Load(GetRandomTetromino(), typeof(GameObject)), new Vector2(5.0f, 20.0f), Quaternion.identity);
    }


    //gonna pass in the mino position in this method to see 
    // if it is still in the grid
    public bool CheckIsInsideGrid(Vector2 pos) 
    {                                          
        return ((int)pos.x >= 0 && (int)pos.x < gridWidth && (int)pos.y >= 0);
    }

    public Vector2 RoundingTheMinoPosition(Vector2 pos)
    {
        return new Vector2(Mathf.Round(pos.x), Mathf.Round(pos.y));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Genreates a random int and assings a teromino prefab to the outcome 
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    string GetRandomTetromino()
    {
        int randomTetromino = Random.Range(1, 8); //
        string randomTetrominoName = null;
        switch (randomTetromino)
        {
            case 1:
                randomTetrominoName = "Prefabs/Tetromino_T";
                break;

            case 2:
                randomTetrominoName = "Prefabs/Tetromino_Long";
                break;

            case 3:
                randomTetrominoName = "Prefabs/Tetromino_Square";
                break;

            case 4:
                randomTetrominoName = "Prefabs/Tetromino_J";
                break;

            case 5:
                randomTetrominoName = "Prefabs/Tetromino_L";
                break;

            case 6:
                randomTetrominoName = "Prefabs/Tetromino_S";
                break;

            case 7:
                randomTetrominoName = "Prefabs/Tetromino_Z";
                break;
        }
        return randomTetrominoName;
    }

}
```

Comment: Post the moving code you call in that if statement!

Comment: I edited my post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I misunderstood the original question. You want to move on "D" key press only but move until your you have reached the Edge when the the "D" key is held down.You need a timer when the the key is held down and this can be done with `Time.deltaTime`. Check while the key is held down with `Input.GetKey`, and if the timer reaches the amount of value you think makes it a held down, then you know the key is held down.

Also, check when the key is released with `Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.D)`. If the key is released but timer has not reached the value you think makes it a held down,then it's simply a key press. It's worth doing this in a coroutine function instead of the `Update` function to simplify it and also reduce the amount of variables required to do it.

```
const float timeToCountAsHeldDown = 0.3f;
float pressTimer = 0;

IEnumerator moveChecker()
{
    while (true)
    {
        //Check when the D key is pressed
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
        {
            //Continue to check if it is still heldown and keep counting the how long
            while (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
            {
                //Start incrementing timer
                pressTimer += Time.deltaTime;

                //Check if this counts as being "Held Down"
                if (pressTimer > timeToCountAsHeldDown)
                {
                    //It a "key held down", call the OnKeyHeldDown function and wait for it to return
                    yield return OnKeyHeldDown();
                    //No need to continue checking for Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D). Break out of this whule loop
                    break;
                }

                //Wait for a frame
                yield return null;
            }
        }


        //Check if "D" key is released 
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.D))
        {
            //Check if we have not not reached the timer then it is only a key press
            if (pressTimer < timeToCountAsHeldDown)
            {
                //It just a key press, call the OnKeyPressedOnly function and wait for it to return
                yield return OnKeyPressedOnly();
            }

            //Reset timer to 0 for the next key press
            pressTimer = 0f;
        }

        //Wait for a frame
        yield return null;
    }
}

IEnumerator OnKeyPressedOnly()
{
    Debug.Log("D key was only Pressed");

    //Move 1 unit only
    transform.position += new Vector3(1, 0, 0);
    yield return null;
}


IEnumerator OnKeyHeldDown()
{
    Debug.LogWarning("D key is Held Down");

    //Don't move for 0.5 seconds 
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);

    //Move 1 unit every frame until edge detection is reached!
    while (!CheckIsValidPosition())
    {
        transform.position += new Vector3(1, 0, 0);

        //Wait for a frame
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course, you probably still want some kind of time-limiter on the "held down" action, as "1 frame" is typically 1/60th of a second and most people's reaction times are closer to 1/4.

Comment: Thanks I will give this a try

Comment: Doing like you suggested and separating both GetKey and GetKeyDown in an IF and ELSE IF resulted in the same behavior as I first had in my original post. So the time-limiter you mentionned is the only thing that I need, or so it seems. But this is what I don't know how to do.

Comment: @MathieuGagne I may have misunderstood the question. You want to move  `Vector3(1, 0, 0);` onc only when D is pressed. If it is presssed and held down, continue to move it?

Comment: yes when I  tap "D", I want to move the block by one world unit per tap. When i hold down "D", I want the game to wait .5 seconds before starting to 
 move the block continuously right until it reaches the edge of the game board.

Comment: I don't understand the last 0.5 part. When key is held down for 0.5 seconds, keep moving until  it reaches the edge of the game board?

Comment: I think what he wants is: a) Single Tab => move 1 Unit; b) Hold button down => Don't move for 0.5 seconds than move infinite until reaching edge. What still is missing: do you also want to move it 1 unit when starting to hold down the button?

Comment: @derHugo That makes sense. Also, your question in the comment  is important to answer this

Comment: @derHugo Yes exactly, a) Single Tab => move 1 Unit; b) Hold button down => Don't move for 0.5 seconds than move infinite until reaching edge. And finally don't I want to move when staring to hold down the button. Basically, I want the same behavior as the original Tetris. But I  realize that this challenge was a bit hard for me.

Comment: I get it now. Do you have your edge detection code? How do you detect when you have reached the edge?

Comment: I edited my OP with the lastest code I have wrote so far. "CheckIsValidPosition()" is for the edge detection (at the bottom of tetromino.cs)

Comment: @MathieuGagne Modified answer match be what derHugo said.

Comment: @Programmer wow this answer is really awesome! I need to try this asap, very smart! I didn't think of using coroutines that way. Thank you very much, I defenitely learned something.

Comment: Yes, coroutines are mostly used for timings, and waiting/delaying in a code. They simplify it.